# Testng report assert and continue test

Tags: selenium, testng, reporting, fluentlenium, assertj

I'm trying to us testng with fluentlenium,  and report it to extent reports.

The problem is that I have asserts throughout the tests and want to report them without using try and catch.

Any ideas how to do it?  Is there a assert listener or something?

Comment: Your question is about TestNG soft asserts, which I gave a good answer to. Now you're changing your question and unaccepting and un-upvoting my answer. I don't really think that is fair to me so I will not be helping you any further. Good luck trying to get it working with assertj as they don't provide a hook like TestNG does..

Comment: Sorry about that you are absolutely right,  I'm not used to ask on stak overflow I just look for weeks until I find something (me and my stupid pride :( )  but this time I have time limit.

Comment: I understand, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to do something like this ( I take screenshots on every assert failure ) is wrap the SoftAssert class like so:

```java
import org.testng.asserts.IAssert;

public class SoftAssert extends org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert {

    @Override
    public void onAssertFailure(IAssert<?> assertCommand, AssertionError ex) {

        LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, assertCommand.getMessage());
        //doReportingStuffHere
        super.onAssertFailure(assertCommand, ex);
    }
}
```

Now every time your soft assertion fails (while it happens, not just at the end) you can do your report stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SoftAssert` of implement `IAssert` on your own

Comment: But in soft assert I can onlt report once at the end,  I want to report with the steps I have done so far

Comment: well there you go..go ahead and implement IAssert on your own then and feel free to play all with it :)

Comment: @MrunalGosar OP now no longer wants to use TestNG asserts for some reason so has no IAssert available anymore.